# How to send automated Commerce Subscription related emails?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce3

What’s the best way to send automated Commerce Subscription related emails? For example, if a user sets up a new subscription they would get sent a confirmation email with details about it, how to cancel etc. Then emails relating to renewals, payment issues, cancellations would follow.

I imagine this could work in a similar way to Commerce order status related emails, with the emails being generated from a template. As far as I can see that’s not something built into Craft, yet, so assuming this needs to be done with event listeners.

Comment: Looking for the same information.

Comment: Me too. Any input please.